# Laravel File Uploads Error: Missing a temporary folder

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, upload, intervention

I'm running a server with Ubuntu 16.04, ISPConfig and Laravel. For tests I got a local Testserver with basically the same settings. Testserver has another domain and no https. I've integrated File Uploads for Laravel on my Testserver. I use http://image.intervention.io/ and it works fine on my Testserver.

The Liveserver fails with it. Can't pass "hasFile" function.

**Form:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{$user->avatar}}" style="width:150px; 
       height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-
       right:25px;">
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
       action="/account/edit/upload_avatar" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="avatar">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function upload_avatar(Request $request)
 {
    dd($request);

    if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
      $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
      $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
      Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( 
      public_path('uploads/avatars/' . $filename));

      $user = Sentinel::getUser();
      $user->avatar = $filename;
      $user->save();

      return back();
    }
  }
```

**Request:**

```
Request {#39 ▼
#json: null
#convertedFiles: null
#userResolver: Closure {#330 ▶}
#routeResolver: Closure {#322 ▶}
+attributes: ParameterBag {#41 ▶}
+request: ParameterBag {#40 ▶}
+query: ParameterBag {#47 ▶}
+server: ServerBag {#44 ▶}
+files: FileBag {#43 ▼
#parameters: array:1 [▼
  "avatar" => UploadedFile {#28 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "2.jpg"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -size: 0
    -error: 6
    path: ""
    filename: ""
    basename: ""
    pathname: ""
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/public"
    aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    inode: false
    size: false
    perms: 00
    owner: false
    group: false
    type: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
      }
    ]
  }
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#42 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#45 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/account/edit/upload_avatar"
  #requestUri: "/account/edit/upload_avatar"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#375 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isClientIpsValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
  }
```

error:6 
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP

Php.ini has the same settings for file uploads as the Testserver.
This is from my php.ini:

```
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default 
 if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Without the if(hasFile) iIget the following:

```
NotReadableException
Unsupported image type. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF 
or WebP files.
```

I've already checked the file permissions for the whole project and even tried it with 777 on the file destination.

Comment: try upload_tmp_dir="<somedirpath>" updating in php.ini

Comment: still the same.

Comment: you need to restart the server after you make changes to php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I know, thanks! Solved it now. Tmp folder Hand wrong permissions.